# How can i prevent the spaces from getting deleted and have my values on 1 line only?

Tags: python, python-3.x

the values in my current .txt file :

```
1256

5679

   t67

y1

     890
```

the end result i want is these values between '' and on 1 line without removing the spaces and distanced by a comma:

```
'1256','5679','   t67','y1','     890'
```

What i tried:

```
output = r""
file_name = r"path"
string_to_add = "','"

with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    file_lines = [''.join([x.strip(), string_to_add, '\n']) for x in f.readlines()]


with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(file_lines)
```

but it didn't work, it removed the spaces and didn't add the values next tp each other

Comment: `x.strip()` removes spaces. Why do you do it? If it is just for removing newlines, do `x.rstrip('\n')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting a wrong result is the `x.strip()` this will remove all whitespace.

Couldn't you just do:

```
#each line is now an entry in a list
data = open(sys.argv[1], 'r').readlines()

#remove newlines before writing to output 
line = ','.join(data)
OUT = open('output.txt','w')
OUT.write(line)
OUT.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`x.strip()` removes spaces, endlines and tabs from both sides of `x`. You want to use `x.rstrip()` instead to only remove trailing spaces and endlines.

You can also directly use your `string_to_add` to join on, instead of what you currently do.

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    file_lines = string_to_add.join(x.rstrip() for x in f.readlines())

with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    f.writeline(file_lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

The method String.strip() works this way: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/strip

It removes the characters you have specified inside of the parenthesis from the string, so not giving any character will make the method to return the same string, I suppose.

The method String.join works this way: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp

It takes the String and uses it to join an iterable of Strings (list, tuple,...)

So what you are doing here is simply adding a ',' to each line of the file.

Try using this:

```py
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
         for line in f.readlines():
              myString += '"' + line + '",'
         myString = myString[:-1]
```